# Can I travel to Dublin, Republic of Ireland with UK Tier 2/Schengen visas with Indian Passport

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland, residency

Can anyone please guide me if I can travel to Dublin for a short trip with UK Tier 2 Visa and an Indian Passport? Additionally I have a valid Schengen Visa stamped on passport as well.

Comment: I think it could be on topic here. Yes he's an expat, but the question is solely whether his current passport status lets him visit Ireland, which is most definitely a travel question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general [Indian nationals require a visa to enter Ireland](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Countries%20whose%20nationals%20are%20visa%20required):

> Nationals of the states or territorial entities listed below are subject to an Irish visa requirement for the purposes of travelling to the State. Possession of a valid Irish visa does not guarantee entry to the State.  An Immigration Officer at the port of entry has the authority to grant or deny admission, and to decide the duration of a person’s stay in the State.
>
> [...]
>
> #### I
>
> India, Republic of

However since you have a valid Tier 2 UK visa you should be allowed to enter Ireland as long as your intended length of stay is less than or equal to 90 days, or until your UK visa expires, as per [the S.I. No. 473/2014 - Immigration Act 2004 (Visas) Order 2014](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/2014/si/473/made/en/print). This rule entered into force in 2014, and is valid until the 31st of October 2016. Quoting from the linked regulation (emphasis mine):

> 3. It is hereby declared that the following classes of non-nationals are specified as classes the members of which are not required to be in possession of a valid Irish visa when landing in the State:
>
>    (a)  nationals of a state or territorial entity specified in Schedule 1;
>
>    (b) non-nationals who are holders of—
>
>    1. a valid Convention travel document issued by Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Germany, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovak Republic, Spain, Sweden, or Switzerland and where the intended purpose of the travel to the State by the holder of such a travel document is solely for a visit of up to a maximum period of 3 months,
>    2. a valid permanent residence card,
>    3. a valid residence card,
>    4. a valid travel document issued by the State for the purposes of Article 28 of the New York Convention, or
>    5. a diplomatic passport issued by a state or territorial entity specified in Schedule 2;
>
>    (c) non-nationals who are family members of a Union citizen and holders of a document called “Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen” as referred to in Article 10 of the Directive of 2004;
>
>    (d)  **until 31 October 2016, United Kingdom visitors who are nationals of a state or territorial entity specified in Schedule 3<sup>1</sup> and where the intended purpose of the travel to the State by the United Kingdom visitor concerned is solely for a visit of the shorter of the following periods—**
>
>    1. **90days or less, or**
>    2. **the remaining period of validity of that person’s leave to enter the United Kingdom, or, as the case may be, leave to remain in the United Kingdom;**
>
>    (e) United Kingdom visitors who are—
>
>    1. nationals of a state or territorial entity specified in Schedule 4, and
>    2. holders of a visa issued by the competent authorities of the United Kingdom that is endorsed by those authorities with the letters “BIVS”,
>
>    where the intended purpose of the travel to the State by the United Kingdom visitor concerned is solely for a visit of the shorter of the following periods—
>
>    1. 90days or less, or
>    2. the remaining period of validity of that person’s leave to enter the United Kingdom, or, as the case may be, leave to remain in the United Kingdom;
>
>    (f) holders of a service passport or public affairs passport who arrive in the State in the company of a Minister of the Government of the People’s Republic of China where that Minister is on an official visit to the State;
>
>    (g) qualifying United Nations officials who are holders of a United Nations laissez-passer referred to in Section 24 of the United Nations Convention.

<sup>1</sup>India is listed in Schedule 3

Comment: I have tier 2 work visa and I landed UK at 20th August. Is there any minimum stay required(at least 3 months completed in UK) before I apply for Schenegan visa? One of my friend applied to German visa, and his application got rejected.

Comment: @Rahul I don't know. And this might need to be asked in a separate question.

Comment: The so called 'Short stay visa waiver programme' you are referring to here, which regulates reciprocal visa recognition between UK and the Republic of Ireland  has been extended to October 31st 2016, does however not apply to this question. Holders of UK visitors visas from the countries in Schedule 3 are allowed to enter Ireland, but not holders of long-term visas (as a tier 2 visa generally is).

Comment: Sorry, I ment 'extended to October 31st 2021'.

Answer (score -1):

No is the answer. As you are a resident of UK you need seperate visa. Visitors on 'C' visas can enter on UK visas.

Comment: Do you have any references for this?

Comment: @JoErNanO If I'm not mistaken, you have quoted the reference yourself and misinterpreted it. The paragraph you have emphazised relates to 'United Kingdom visitors', which in all the interpretations of the act I have seen is ment as 'foreigners who have entered the UK on a visitor visa'. A tier 2 visa is *not* a visitor visa.