# Chinese national with UK permanent residency requires visa to travel to Ireland?

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, chinese-citizens

Background: I'm an Irish citizen; my girlfriend is a Chinese citizen; we both live and work in London UK; she has a permanent residence card to remain in the UK.

My girlfriend would like to visit my family in Ireland for Christmas, and we're worried we've left it a little late to apply for a tourist visa for her. I'm trying to figure out if she will actually need a visa, but I'm having trouble interpreting the legislation.

Based on [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/57253), and, by extension, [this statute](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/inis/si%20no%20473%20of%202014.pdf/Files/si%20no%20473%20of%202014.pdf), it seems that Chinese nationals visiting the UK with a valid UK visa are eligible to visit Ireland.

> (d) until 31 October 2016, United Kingdom visitors who are nationals
>   of a state or territorial entity specified in Schedule 3 and where the
>   intended purpose of the travel to the State by the United Kingdom
>   visitor concerned is solely for a visit of the shorter of the
>   following periods -

(People's Republic of China does appear in schedule 3)

Where I'm confused is whether or not a permanent residency card counts as a visa, and whether a permanent resident in the UK counts as a "visitor". If not, it would seem that this clause does not apply, and she would need a tourism visa. On the other hand, if she does count as a visitor to the UK, does that mean she doesn't need a visa for Ireland?

Comment: She needs a visa to visit the ROI, despite the absence of border controls and an open land border.  Also... there is enough time to apply successfully to the ROI for a visitor visa.

Comment: If you're short on time you may want to consider using a visa expediting agent. I once had to travel to China on very short notice (approx 5 days) and got a visa in time this way (normally takes 2 or 3 weeks if I recall correctly). You might be able to achieve a time saving for an Irish visa. The cost wasn't too bad - about £50 on top of the normal visa fee. It also came with additional benefits in that it saved multiple trips and lots of hassle dealing with an embassy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question appears to be answered by [FAQs](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Information%20Note%20-%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme%20October%202014.pdf/Files/Information%20Note%20-%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme%20October%202014.pdf) 13 and 15:

> 13. I am resident in one of the countries covered by the Programme but a national of another country. Can I avail of the Programme?
>
> Only passport holders of those countries are included in the scheme.
>   Residents in those countries, who are not nationals of that country,
>   are not covered.

and more specifically in 15:

> 15. I am a national of one of the countries covered but am a long-term
>       resident in the UK or the Schengen area. Can I avail of the Programme?
>
> Nationals of the countries above, who are long-term legal residents in
>   the UK or the Schengen area, will still require an Irish visa but will
>   have the visa fee waived as part of the Programme.
>
> The visa fee is usually €60 per person, including children, for a
>   single visit, or €100 for a multi-entry visa.
>
> Visa applicants will see comprehensive guidelines on making a visa
>   application and may follow links to make an online application at:
>
> www.inis.gov.ie

There's an explicit example given at the end of the document: UK long term visas holders must get an Irish visa.

Comment: Interesting that this seems to contradict with where I got to from the above linked immigration law.

Comment: @CMaster, yes. The contradiction between this FAQ and the printed law is confusing. However, I think that as this FAQ is quite explicit it seems to trump your (seemingly valid) reading of the law.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something?