# Can I travel to Dublin with a Permanent Residence (UK)?

Tags: visas, uk, ireland, sri-lankan-citizens

I have Permanent Residence in UK and would need to travel to Dublin for Business. Do I have to get visa? or can I travel without it? It would only be for 1 day.

Comment: You don't mention your citizenship, which I think is relevant.
See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59387/chinese-national-with-uk-permanent-residency-requires-visa-to-travel-to-ireland (not sure if ti is a duplicate yet though)

Comment: @CMaster I have a Sri Lankan Passport. I checked the link you had attached and concluded i do need visa. http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/fees - When i looked on this page for the application process it states that Sri Lankan citizens does not need to pay an application fee. Does this mean I only have to fill in the online application? Do i not have to send my passport or something?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes you need a visa. I had it confirmed from the Irish embassy when I wanted to travel to Ireland.

Comment: @DumbCoder Great! Thanks so much. Where did you find the online application?

Comment: I have a Indian passport and UK residents permit can i go irland without visa

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, and you have found out yourself, you do need a visa as a Sri Lankan passport holder, irrespective of what permanent residence permits you hold.

You can do this by visiting [this link](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit+Tourist), reading it, then clicking the 'Apply for a visa' button at the bottom of the page. If you would like to do any further reading in addition to the previous link, you could also have a look at [this one](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/travel_and_recreation/travel_to_ireland/visas_for_tourists_visiting_ireland.html).

Hope that helps. Good luck with your application.