# What is the correct procedure for a visa national to enter Ireland by land?

Tags: uk, ireland, northern-ireland

A few years ago I travelled to the Republic of Ireland from the UK, taking a ferry to Belfast and driving across the border from NI. As a UK national this wasn't a problem, but I'm trying to work out how it would work if I weren't.

For this scenario, let's assume:

- I have a valid UK long-term visa
- I'm not eligible for the Irish visa waiver scheme for holders of UK visas

As stated in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59387/chinese-national-with-uk-permanent-residency-requires-visa-to-travel-to-ireland) I would need to get an Irish visa, but once I had it would it be legal to just cross the border, or would I need to report somewhere to have it checked / get my passport stamped?

Comment: It would be legal to just cross the border, however you need to report as soon as possible (within reason) to the closest checkpoint to have it checked / get your passport stamped.