# For an Indian citizen, will a UK Tier 2 short term ICT visa be sufficient to travel to the Republic of Ireland and fly back to UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

Having Indian citizenship, will a UK Tier 2 short term visa be sufficient to travel to the Republic of Ireland (Not Northern Ireland")? 
I have spent a few weeks in UK and my visa allows me to spend another month here. Also I am planning to return to UK before the visa expires.

Comment: @Dorothy this question asks about "Ireland" the one you pointed is of "Northern Ireland". Please note countries are different.

Comment: Why the scare quotes around Ireland? Its name is not a matter of controversy.

Comment: @PrashantZombade Be aware that the accepted answer to this question is out of date and was IMHO even false at the time of writing. Mmmmmm's answer is correct: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56965/can-i-travel-to-dublin-republic-of-ireland-with-uk-tier-2-schengen-visas-with-i

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: According to what? Can you provide some documentary evidence for your claim, or are we to once again just take your word for it? I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying you need to _demonstrate_ that you are right :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have commented both answers in the question we are talking about, explaining why I think the accepted answer is wrong and why I think the downvoted answer is correct. And I am not going to explain to you for a second time why I don't have to demonstrate anything.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: And I am not going to explain to you for a third why you do :) Good day.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo yes I am hopeful answer is Yes. Also  just now I got reply from this Indian person who asked this question >> question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56965/can-i-travel-to-dublin-republic-of-ireland-with-uk-tier-2-schengen-visas-with-i   and Good News is he Did Visit Ireland with Tier 2 Visa! Not a single problem he faced. (I was not sure whether he visited or not, hence I asked my question, perhaps duplicate). So I believe I can still go ahead with Ireland tour. Also the Visa waiver program is extended till 2021. Hushhhhh.....

Comment: @PrashantZombade I have also never faced a problem driving drunk, speeding or stealing money from old ladies. That does not mean that it is ok to do so, just that I was lucky and noone caught me. I can of course not force you to doubt the accepted answer to the other question, but I strongly suggest that you read the official description of the visa waiver program and realize that it does not apply to your situation: http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish+Short+Stay+Visa+Waiver+Programme